# Undefined variable $username on line 19 PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and trying to see the uniqueid of an uploaded image but I'm getting an error that says "Undefined variable $username on line 19" ($new_img_name = uniqid($username, true).'.'.$img_ex_to_lc;), not sure why this is. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php


    if (isset($_FILES['pfp']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['pfp']['name'])) {
    
    $fileName = $_FILES['pfp']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['pfp']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['pfp']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['pfp']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['pfp']['type'];

    if ($fileError === 0) {
        $img_ex = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $img_ex_to_lc = strtolower($img_ex);

        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

        if(in_array($img_ex_to_lc, $allowed )) {
            $new_img_name = uniqid($username, true).'.'.$img_ex_to_lc;
            echo $new_img_name;
        } else {
            $em = "You cannot upload files of this type";
            header("Location: ..index.html?error=$em&$data");
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        $em = "Unkown error occurred!";
        header("Location: ..index.html?error=$em&$data");
        exit;
    }
    
}
```

?>

Comment: Well it's fairly simple...have a look at your code: where did you define and populate a variable called $username? There's nothing like that shown here, before you then try to use it as input into the uniqid function. You're trying to use something which doesn't exist. Where do you think that data is supposed to come from?

Comment: @ADyson I tried $username = $_POST['username']; before, but it just gave me "Undefined array key 'username'"

Comment: Well that probably means your form doesn't have a "username" field in it. Are you _expecting_ that data to come from the submitted form? If not, where should it come from?

Comment: Funny, you have `if(isset(...) && !empty(...))` for `$fileName`, but you didn't think to use that same approach for `$_POST['username']`? It's fine to be new to PHP, but you should see the things you're doing **in your code**, and maybe try to use them again  This also works in a ternary (in-line if/else statement), like `$username = isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : 'unknown';`; `$username` will be whatever is uploaded, or `'unknown'` if nothing is provided.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks, it worked! I was watching a tutorial but they did it differently, but I still got the results, so thanks.

Comment: Ah gotcha; I was wondering if that was the case  But no worries! Learning by trial and error is generally an effective method, and eventually it should all click into place. Glad you got it working; cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that username is an available option you will have to define it in the section that you have the rest of your variables

```
$fileName = $_FILES['pfp']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['pfp']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['pfp']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['pfp']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['pfp']['type'];

$username = {Define username variable here}
```

Comment: "username" isn't one of the fields available via $_FILES - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php